# Excluding particular files when merging two different trees

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When merging two different `Trees`, is it possible to exclude certain `Filetypes` from merging?

I.e. I want to merge all `.cs-files` but the `.csproj-files` should stay the same in each folder.

Everything I tried does not have the effect I'd like to reach

I.e. Adding properties:

```
svn:ignore
svn:global-ignore
ignore-on-commit
```

Because they remove the file from the repository completely.

Thanks in advance.